# HTMLPurifier iframe Vimeo and Youtube video

Tags: php, video, iframe, xss, htmlpurifier

How can I use HTMLPurifier to filter xss but also to allow iframe Vimeo and Youtube video?

```
require_once 'htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('HTML.Trusted', true);

$config->set('Filter.YouTube', true);
$config->set('HTML.DefinitionID', '1');
$config->set('HTML.SafeObject', 'true');
$config->set('Output.FlashCompat', 'true');

$config->set('HTML.FlashAllowFullScreen', 'true');

$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
$temp = $purifier->purify($temp);
```

Answer (score 39):

HTMLPurifier version 4.4.0 has new configuration directives to allow YouTube and Vimeo iframes:

```
//allow iframes from trusted sources
$cfg->set('HTML.SafeIframe', true);
$cfg->set('URI.SafeIframeRegexp', '%^(https?:)?//(www\.youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com/embed/|player\.vimeo\.com/video/)%'); //allow YouTube and Vimeo
```

- http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#HTML.SafeIframe
- http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#URI.SafeIframeRegexp

Comment: Does it preserve the `allowfullscreen` attribute for YouTube and the `webkitAllowFullScreen`, `mozallowfullscreen`, and `allowFullScreen` attributes for Vimeo?

Comment: No, but in my tests it had no effect on either the Flash or HTML5 player. Fullscreen worked no matter what. Plus, it's not in the specs, so it's probably safe to ignore. See http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-customize.html#addAttribute for adding custom attributes.

Comment: @Malte How to also allow facebook video iframe

Comment: @PanagiotisKoursaris add it to the regex like so `%^(https?:)?//(www\.youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com/embed/|player\.vimeo\.com/video/|www\.facebook\.com/plugins/video.php\?)%`

Answer (score 10):

For anyone who is struggling (how to enable iframe and allowfullscreen)

```
    $config = \HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
    $config->set('HTML.SafeIframe', true);
    $config->set('URI.SafeIframeRegexp', '%^(https?:)?//(www\.youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com/embed/|player\.vimeo\.com/video/)%'); //allow YouTube and Vimeo
    // This line is important allow iframe in allowed elements or it will not work    
    $config->set('HTML.AllowedElements', array('iframe'));// <-- IMPORTANT
    $config->set('HTML.AllowedAttributes','iframe@src,iframe@allowfullscreen');

    $def = $config->getHTMLDefinition(true);
    $def->addAttribute('iframe', 'allowfullscreen', 'Bool');

    $purifier = new \HTMLPurifier($config);
    $purifiedHtml = $purifier->purify($html);
```

Comment: Thanks, tried all possible solutions to this problem, but your answer solved it! Thanks a million!

Comment: Your answer solved it but width, height elements got removed

Comment: @VikasChauhan 6th line

Comment: It worked but when I set iframe as bool it does not work
because in youtube embed code  - allowfullscreen="" attribute does not work.

However I changed tha line - 
$def->addAttribute('iframe', 'allowfullscreen', 'Bool'); to
$def->addAttribute('iframe', 'allowfullscreen', 'Text');
Finally worked for me...

Comment: @sumeet How to also allow  facebook video iframe

Answer (score 9):

I just read [this blog entry](http://sachachua.com/blog/2011/08/drupal-html-purifier-embedding-iframes-youtube/), and successfully created and used the custom filter.  I made some changes to the code and added Vimeo support:

```
/**
 * Based on: http://sachachua.com/blog/2011/08/drupal-html-purifier-embedding-iframes-youtube/
 * Iframe filter that does some primitive whitelisting in a somewhat recognizable and tweakable way
 */
class HTMLPurifier_Filter_MyIframe extends HTMLPurifier_Filter
{
    public $name = 'MyIframe';

    /**
     *
     * @param string $html
     * @param HTMLPurifier_Config $config
     * @param HTMLPurifier_Context $context
     * @return string
     */
    public function preFilter($html, HTMLPurifier_Config $config, HTMLPurifier_Context $context)
    {
        $html = preg_replace('#<iframe#i', '<img class="MyIframe"', $html);
        $html = preg_replace('#</iframe>#i', '</img>', $html);
        return $html;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param string $html
     * @param HTMLPurifier_Config $config
     * @param HTMLPurifier_Context $context
     * @return string
     */
    public function postFilter($html, HTMLPurifier_Config $config, HTMLPurifier_Context $context)
    {
        $post_regex = '#<img class="MyIframe"([^>]+?)>#';
        return preg_replace_callback($post_regex, array($this, 'postFilterCallback'), $html);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param array $matches
     * @return string
     */
    protected function postFilterCallback($matches)
    {
        // Domain Whitelist
        $youTubeMatch = preg_match('#src="https?://www.youtube(-nocookie)?.com/#i', $matches[1]);
        $vimeoMatch = preg_match('#src="http://player.vimeo.com/#i', $matches[1]);
        if ($youTubeMatch || $vimeoMatch) {
            $extra = ' frameborder="0"';
            if ($youTubeMatch) {
                $extra .= ' allowfullscreen';
            } elseif ($vimeoMatch) {
                $extra .= ' webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen';
            }
            return '<iframe ' . $matches[1] . $extra . '></iframe>';
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }
}
```

Adding the filter to your HTML Purifier config

```
$config->set('Filter.Custom', array(new HTMLPurifier_Filter_MyIframe()));
```

Comment: i didn't work for me at first. but then i allowed img (because the filter uses the img tag to do the magic) and worked! $config->set('HTML.Allowed', 'p,a[href|rel|target],img[class|src|height|width]');

Answer (score 3):

This much should do the trick

```
$text = "<iframe width='560' height='315' src='//www.youtube.com/embed/RGLI7QBUitE?autoplay=1' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>";

require_once 'htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('HTML.Trusted', true);
$config->set('Filter.YouTube', true);

echo $purifier->purify($text);
```

Comment: Just added the line 
> $config->set('Filter.YouTube', true); 
It worked for me.
Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Based on *reverbnation*'s answer, I realized that for some reason the line

```
$def->addAttribute('iframe', 'allowfullscreen', 'Bool');
```

did not work correctly and instead of

```
allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"
```

HTMLPurifier was outputting

```
allowfullscreen=""
```

Although the [documentation](http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-customize.html#addAttribute) says that `Bool - Boolean attribute, with only one valid value: the name of the attribute`, I tried to use `Enum` instead:

```
$def->addAttribute('iframe', 'allowfullscreen', 'Enum#allowfullscreen');
```

The third parameter means that `allowfullscreen` attribute will have only correct value -- `allowfullscreen`, everything else will be ignored. This way we have the same behaviour as with `Bool`. Luckily, it worked for me.

Perhaps this solution will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the %HTML.Trusted, %Filter.YouTube and %HTML.DefinitionID. They're probably interacting poorly with SafeObject/FlashCompat.

Comment: iframe still blocked anyway, no metter. Do you know another good solutions but with iframe support?

Comment: Oh yeah, you'll have to add Iframe support separately. Here's one possible way of doing it: http://htmlpurifier.org/phorum/read.php?3,4646,4646#msg-4646 And of course we're hoping to (eventually) add support for it properly in the core.

Comment: I tried this solution, but i have problem, here my last comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135755/how-do-i-allow-script-object-param-embed-and-iframe-tags-in-htmlpurifier

Comment: Why has youtube switched to iframes? Whhyyyyyyyy?  /despairing cry

Comment: @ElYobo because HTML5 video

Answer (score 0):

Using drupal 7.19 and the htmlpurifier module you can configure the following setting without needing to write this code.

See http://drupal.org/node/711728#comment-5600344

Answer (score 0):

Also do not forget to set

```
URI.DisableExternalResources: false
```

if you've set it to `true` before.