# PHP strip iframe except YouTube with regular expression

Tags: php, iframe, youtube, strip

I want to strip all iframe from HTML except YouTube.

I've tried with this code with caret sign to except YouTube keyword but it didn't work.

```
$search[] = '@<iframe[^(youtube)]*?>.*?</iframe>@si';
$text = preg_replace($search, '', $document);
```

Comment: It's really hard if not impossible to use regex for this. What if the tag is `<iframe src="maliciousaddress" decoy="youtube">` or `<iframe src="maliciousaddress.com/?youtube">`?

Comment: it's doesn't matter, because this html code come from trusted source. that's mean there's no malicious code. i only need to strip useless iframe (facebook) etc ... and i need to keep youtube iframe only.

Answer (score 0):

Since googling up `php strip tags except youtube` linked me here, I think I should give a go at suggesting an alternative answer.

Maybe you'd like to use a library like [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)? Malte already suggested a way of doing this in https://stackoverflow.com/a/12784081/2716927.

Untested code but should work pretty much like this:

```
require_once 'htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';

$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('HTML.Trusted', true);
$config->set('HTML.SafeIframe', true);
$config->set('URI.SafeIframeRegexp', '%^(https?:)?//(www\.youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com/embed/|player\.vimeo\.com/video/)%'); //allow YouTube and Vimeo
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);

$text = $purifier->purify($document);
```

Comment: Shout to all: don't use `HTML.Trusted` unless you REALLY know what you are doing.