# HTMLPurifier custom filter configuration

Tags: drupal-7, htmlpurifier

I've seen many posts on various sites which talk about adding "to your HTML Purifier config", like Sonny's excellent response to this question: [HTMLPurifier iframe Vimeo and Youtube video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739284/htmlpurifier-iframe-vimeo-and-youtube-video)

However, try as I might, I can't seem to discover exactly how to set up my HTML Purifier config. I'm actually trying to add a custom filter *a la* Sonny's comment, but the closest I can come to discovering how to set up my HTML purifier config in my Drupal 7 environment is from /sites/all/modules/htmlpurifier/config/sample.php:

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * This file is a sample advanced PHP configuration file for the HTML Purifier
 * filter module. In reality, this file would be named N.php, where N is the
 * integer identifying the filter this is configuring. The configure page
 * for HTML Purifier (advanced) will tell you what file to copy this to.
 *
 * See this URI:
 *
 *    http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html
 *
 * For full information about permitted directives. The most interesting ones
 * for custom configuration are ones with the 'mixed' type, as they cannot
 * be configured using the webform.
```

But this hasn't helped me at all - I don't see anything on the HTML Purifier (advanced) configure page (on the text filter config page? I don't see anything there...), and the doc at the URI above didn't help, either.

Edit: much thanks to @Chris for his answer to my original question.  I subsequently found that creating the filtered_html.php file removes the ability for me to configure HTML Purifier for Filtered HTML from the UI! Is this supposed to happen?

All that I see from the UI when looking at HTML Purifier (Advanced) is the checkbox for "Display help text".  (I already added this as a comment below, but I thought I'd modify my question as well in the hopes that more people would see this...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure you have the HTML purifier library installed as show in the INSTALL.txt file.  The status report page will show you the version if it's installed correctly.

In Drupal 7 the filter system now uses string keys rather than integer.  So to create a configuration file for the format "Filtered HTML" under sites/all/modules/htmlpurifier/config/, copy sample.php to filtered_html.php, and update the hook function name like this:

```
function htmlpurifier_config_filtered_html($config) {
```

The rest of the tutorial above worked for me, and now my preFilter and postFilter functions are being called.

I thought you could do this through the UI, but it looks like the "Filters" custom configuration box is not evaluated as PHP.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Chris!  I have HTML Filter installed and running just fine, as evidenced by the fact that it's filtering out my YouTube embeds :-)  If you look at the link I provided and check out Sonny's response, you'll see that he mentions "adding the following to your HTML Purifier config:"

Comment: `code` $config->set('Filter.Custom', array(new HTMLPurifier_Filter_MyIframe()));`code` I tried adding that line to the Filter section of the "HTML PUrifier (advanced)" settings in the Drupal admin panel, but that resulted in a PHP error from HTML Purifier, so I figured that wasn't the proper place to add that statement.

Comment: In addition, I just confirmed that the Status Report page shows I have version 4.4.0 of HTML Purifier installed, with no reported problems.  Also, I am able to add tags to the HTML - Allowed section of the config for HTML Purifier (advanced) in the UI, and those tags are then allowed - so I've been able to do that much without any problems.

Comment: Ok, it looks like the "Custom" textarea under the "Filter" heading should be doing the work of $config->set('Filter.Custom'...  So in that box, try pasting

Comment: array(new HTMLPurifier_Filter_MyIframe());
Click the field label to see the help for that field.  It says it should be an array.

Comment: I get the same error: 
Fatal error: Call to a member function preFilter() on a non-object in /home/ccp/public_html/sites/all/libraries/htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier.php on line 167

Comment: I tried this out and reproduced the error you got.  Turns out the filter custom box in the UI isn't evaluated as PHP.  And the documentation on creating custom filter hooks in php is slightly dated.  I've updated my answer to reflect my findings, and now I think it will work.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I got sidetracked from this task for a couple of days by other parts of the project, but your updated answer worked perfectly just now when I was finally able to try it out.

Comment: I just discovered that creating the filtered_html.php file removes the ability for me to configure HTML Purifier for Filtered HTML from the UI! Is this supposed to happen?  All that I see from the UI when looking at HTML Purifier (Advanced) is the checkbox for "Display help text".