# Yii1 - HtmlPurifier removes allowfullscreen attribute

Tags: php, regex, iframe, yii, htmlpurifier

I am using below configuration to clean the input from user in my Yii project using its inbuilt support for HtmlPurifier

```
array(
        'URI.AllowedSchemes' => array(
            'http' => true,
            'https' => true,
        ),
        "HTML.SafeEmbed" => true,
        'HTML.TargetBlank' => true,
        "HTML.SafeIframe" => true,
        "Filter.YouTube" => true,
        'URI.SafeIframeRegexp' => '%^(https?:)?//(www\.youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com/embed/|player\.vimeo\.com/video/)%'
    ),
```

**Example:-**

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Xe2nlti47kA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Above Url when saved after purifying gets converted to below iframe code

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Xe2nlti47kA" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

How can we allow allowfullscreen attribute as safe ? Does any change in regex will solve this or need to apply a custom solution ?

Comment: The 'problem' seems to be that HTML Purifier does not have a `allowfullscreen => 'Bool#allowfullscreen'` attribute for `<iframe>` tags at all: http://repo.or.cz/w/htmlpurifier.git/blob/HEAD:/library/HTMLPurifier/HTMLModule/Iframe.php - basically, HTML Purifier can only leave attributes and tags in tact that it _understands the structure of_, which in this case isn't given. You can try patching that file (haven't tried this, don't recommend it, _but_ has the benefit of being quick), *or* you can take a look at the customisation documentation: http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-customize.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a useful link which will solve the answer.....We need to implement a custom class to allow the "allowfullscreen" attribute. This will add this attribute on purified iframe code.

Reference
http://sachachua.com/blog/2011/08/drupal-html-purifier-embedding-iframes-youtube/
Answered by Sonny
[HTMLPurifier iframe Vimeo and Youtube video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739284/htmlpurifier-iframe-vimeo-and-youtube-video)

Steps

1) Include the class from above url .

2) Set Filter.custom exactly in way shown in above url.

Setting Html Purifier options can be in different in frameworks.

Answer (score -1):

Use the next param in HtmlPurifier config.

```
HTML.IframeAllowFullscreen: true
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it