# Using <iframe> inside a Twig PHP form to submit to database

Tags: php, html, iframe, twig

Sorta basic Twig question here, I'm trying to place an iframe inside a Twig PHP form. **The form works** with normal text "Yellow dog, blue bunny", but it doesn't see the form as being filled out when I put an iframe code inside the form.

videos.php

```
'embed-code'   => 'required|min:100',
```

VideosController.php

```
'embed-code'     => $this->purify($this->request->getPost("embed-code")),
```

HtmlForm

```
 <form method="post" action="{{ url('videos/add') }}" id="postform">
                        <div class="form-row form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                                <label>YouTube Embed Code*</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control {{ errors['embed-code'] is defined ? 'border-danger' : '' }}" name="embed-code">
                            </div>
                        
                    </div>
```

**Again, the form works 100% WITH NORMAL TEXT, but it doesn't recognize iframe code, it will just say "embed-code is required"**

Comment: Is your input in the iframe? The form won't see it if so. If not, can you update your code to show where you're putting the iframe in at?

Comment: No, so what I'm doing is using an HTML form that will put the iframe code inside the database. It works with normal text, but once I put an iframe in the form it doesn't read it. The iframe is youtube embed videos. The iframe get's submitted to the database.

Comment: Ahh, I bet it's purifier removing the iframe code then. You probably have to whitelist it.

Looks like this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739284/htmlpurifier-iframe-vimeo-and-youtube-video