# Add youtube embed for htmlpurifier so that it works with ckeditor?

Tags: php, ckeditor, htmlpurifier

I have tried multiple solutions, but nothing seems to work for me.

This is my current code:

```
      > $config = \HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
        $config->set(
                'HTML.ForbiddenElements',
                'script',
        );
        $config->set('HTML.AllowedElements', array(
            'b','i', 'u', 'blockquote', 'div', 'a', 'img', 'hr',  'p', 'span', 'table', 'tr', 'td', 'th', 'strong','strong', 'em', 'a'
        ));

        $config->set('HTML.AllowedAttributes', array(
            'href', 'style', 'src', 'alt', 'width', 'height', 
        ));


        $purifier = new \HTMLPurifier($config);
        $clean_html = $purifier->purify(html_entity_decode($text));
```

I am trying to integrate it with the Embed youtube option from ckeditor.
Tried this solution, but it did not work [HTMLPurifier iframe Vimeo and Youtube video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739284/htmlpurifier-iframe-vimeo-and-youtube-video/38130320)

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Can you add the HTML that ckeditor is generating and the HTML Purifier output you're getting to your question?